# Good datastructure to count # of keys between two specified keys

Tags: data-structures

Was going through a hypothetical scenario in my head and couldn't quite think of a datastructure to use in this situation. Assume all we need is the ability to add() & remove() keys and then count(key1, key2) the number of keys between the two specified (inclusive). We are assuming of course that these keys overload the comparison operators so they can definitively be less than, greater than, or equal to each other. So for instance, if we inserted 1, 5, 3, 4, 7 and then ran count(1, 4), we would get a resulting output of 3 since we could count the keys 1, 3, and 4.

Now we could do this with a binary search tree using recursion in O(n) time, but what if we needed count() to run in O(log(n)) time? Is there a datastructure out there that you could potentially modify to perform this?

At first I thought maybe we could use an heap or BST and keep track of the number of children on each side. But then I just got really lost trying to trace it out on paper.

Comment: If each tree node contains the number of nodes in each of its subtrees then you don't need to recurse the whole tree  - you just need to find the first and last key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) is a modification of a BST that allows you to query, for any value, how many elements of the tree are smaller than that value. You can then count how many items are in the range (a, b) by asking how many items are less than a, then subtracting out how many items are less than b.

Each operation on an order statistic tree (add, remove, lookup, and count) takes time O(log n), so this lets you solve your particular problem in time O(log n) as well.

Comment: It's worth adding that O(log n) is theoretically optimal, because if you can implement this operation in O(f) time then you can do comparison-sorting in O(n * f) time.

Comment: There are non-comparison based data structures that can outperform this if you’re, say, storing integers that fit into machine words.